# User is notified when new content is created using Rules

Tags: 8, rules, group

I created two groups in one group type.

- Job Post
- Business

Each group has its own content type(same label) and group permissions.

User Story:

"As a user(Job Post) I would like to be able to create a job. A job should contain a description and a job type - for example, plumbing."

As a plumber(Business) I would like to be notified every time a new job is posted that is for plumbing, but not for any other types of work."

How specifically can this be achieve using Rules as I'm a newbie on this module and still trying hard to make setup on this problem.

Comment: If you're new to the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, then you may not be aware of [this](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/a/3616/39516) showstopper ... Apart from that, which module are you using, if any, for implementing those "groups"?

Comment: I'm using Group module. I have also Pathauto enabled.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your setup. A simple way to achieve this would be to assign business users with a role let's say "Business". Once that's done you can create a trigger on creation of new node, set conditions based on your requirement e.g. user role = "Business" and category = "Plumber" and action to send out an email.

You might need additional modules if you're looking at sending out HTML emails.

Let me know if you need any help.

Thanks

Comment: Okey, thanks for your response. Yes, I have a role assigned to each. It is set in the group configuration by the Group module. Also, in my case I only want business to be notified in their page, not in email. Like if we can create a view that whenever a new job post was created for plumbing it will be added in the list view.

Comment: Yes you can do that by using some private messaging module like https://www.drupal.org/project/message_private or can create a new content type with user reference field attached to it. This user reference should point to the business where this message needs to be displayed. You can then create a view and list of all the nodes with user reference set to currently logged in business. You can also add a status field in content type to mark it as unread node and when a business views it, update it to read status.

Comment: Okey, sound like a solution to me. Will follow your instructions and update you. Thanks!